# GremlinPipeline returns different results with Titan and OrientDB

Tags: java, shortest-path, gremlin, orientdb, titan

I am trying to find the shortest path with `GremlinPipeline` using the following code:

```
final GremlinPipeline<String, List> pathPipe = new GremlinPipeline<String, List>(v1)
            .as("similar")
            .both("similar")
            .loop("similar", new PipeFunction<LoopBundle<Vertex>, Boolean>() {
                //@Override
                public Boolean compute(LoopBundle<Vertex> bundle) {
                    return bundle.getLoops() < 5 && bundle.getObject() != v2;
                }
            })
            .path();
```

I have two scenarios. The first is that the data are stored in a Titan graph database and the second  in a OrientDB graph database. When I use the above code with the first scenario I get a list that each entry corresponds to the path that connects vertex v1 and v2. The first entry is always the shortest path.. e.g.

```
[v[4], v[8]]
[v[4], v[20868], v[8]]
[v[4], v[4], v[8]]
[v[4], v[25800], v[8]]
```

(4 is the id of v1 and 8 the id of node 2)

But when I use the above code with orientDB data I get different results, e.g.

```
[v[#9:0], v[#9:0], v[#9:0]] 
[v[#9:0], v[#9:0], v[#9:1]]  
[v[#9:0], v[#9:0], v[#9:45]] 
[v[#9:0], v[#9:0], v[#9:55]]
```

(#9:0 is the id of the v1 and #9:1 is the id of v2)

Note that I print the results using the following code:

```
Iterator iter = pathPipe.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iter.next());
    }
```

EDIT: I use orientdb-1.6.1, titan 0.4.1, blueprints-core-2.5.0 and blueprints-orient-graph-2.5.0

Comment: Could you please report the Blueprints and OrientDB versions?

Comment: I would suggest to run in NonTx to see if the error is the same. Just use OrientGraphNoTx.

Comment: I used OrientGraphNoTx but the output is the same

Comment: Do you know which result is correct? (Or are both results possible answers?)